# C# tuple deconstructor inside another tuple constructor

Tags: c#

Is there C# feature to deconstruct tuple into subset fields of anoter tuple?

```
public (bool, int) f1() => (true, 1);
public (double, bool, int) f2 => (1.0, f1() /*!!here!!*/);
```

Thanks!

Comment: No. There is not.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/424

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no such C# feature, so you will have to write `f2()` as

```
public (double, bool, int) f2()
{
    var tuple = f1();
    return (1.0, tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
}
```

However if you really wanted to, you could write a helper class to combine tuples:

```
public static class TupleCombiner
{
    public static (T1, T2, T3) Combine<T1, T2, T3>(T1 item, (T2, T3) tuple)
    {
        return (item, tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
    }

    public static (T1, T2, T3) Combine<T1, T2, T3>((T1, T2) tuple, T3 item)
    {
        return (tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2, item);
    }

    // Etc for other combinations if needed
}
```

Then if you put `using static YourNamespace.TupleCombiner;` at the top of the code file your code would look like this:

```
public static (bool, int)         f1() => (true, 1);
public static (double, bool, int) f2() => Combine(1.0, f1());
public static (bool, int, double) f3() => Combine(f1(), 1.0);
```

Of course, this also works for `var` declarations inside methods:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var tuple = Combine(1.0, f1());
}
```

I'm not convinced this is in any way worth it, but it's an option.

Also note that - as pointed out by /u/Ry- in the comments - There is [a proposal for tuple "splatting"](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/424) on Github, but that proposal is over three years old (and it doesn't really seem to be exactly what you're asking for).